# Show message when there's no excerpt - Django templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I have this field on a Django template:

```
<p class="border_dotted_bottom">
                          {{ expert.description|slice:":300"  }}
<a href="{% url 'profile' expert.username %}">{% trans "read more" %}</a>....
</p>
```

If this object (user) has no 'decription' (a text field) it shows the word 'None', I need to get rid of that, maybe if he doesn't have a 'description' then show a Simple text and then "read more"

So far, I've tried this:

```
        <p class="border_dotted_bottom">
            {{ % if expert.description >= 1 %}}
            {{ expert.description|slice:":300" }}
                {{% else %}}
            Éste usuario por el momento no tiene descripción
        <a href="{% url 'profile' expert.username %}">{% trans "read more" %}</a>....
         </p>
```

But it doesn't work, I think it's just a typo, or maybe something to do with the conditional I'm using here...

Anybody can shed some light on this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with your `if/else` tags. You have this:

```
{{ % if ... %}}
  ...
{{% else %}}
  ...
```

First off, you need to surround `if/else` by `{% %}`, not `{{% %}}`. Secondly, you don't have an `endif`. An `if/else` block should look like this:

```
{% if ... %}
  ...
{% else %}
  ...
{% endif %}
```

Therefore, your desired block would look something like this:

```
<p class="border_dotted_bottom">
  {% if expert.description >= 1 %}
    {{ expert.description|slice:":300" }}
  {% else %}
    Éste usuario por el momento no tiene descripción
  {% endif %}
  <a href="{% url 'profile' expert.username %}">{% trans "read more" %}</a>....
</p>
```

That being said, you should be able to simplify this using Django's built-in [`default` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#default) or [`default_if_none` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#default-if-none), depending on whether you want to give a default if `expert.description` is equal to `''`/`None` or only `None`:

```
<p class="border_dotted_bottom">
  {{ expert.description|default:"Éste usuario por el momento no tiene descripción"|slice:":300" }}
  <a href="{% url 'profile' expert.username %}">{% trans "read more" %}</a>....
</p>
```

Comment: This made it: '  {{ expert.description|default:"Éste usuario por el momento no tiene descripción"|slice:":300" }}'